# How to also update user's name and image in comments sub-collection in Flutter via Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, users can comment on every post and the comments are stored in the post's sub-collection: 'comments'. Each comments' document contains the poster's username, profile image, user Id, comment Id and some other fields.

So I'm trying to also update each comments' document that contains a current user's userId when that user updates their profile.

I have only been able to achieve the code below;

```
//Uploading the new image to storage
      final firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
      final String uids = firebaseUser.uid;
      final Reference storageReference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("userImages- $uids");
      UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageTemp);
      String downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();

      //Updating users' document with the new image
      final CollectionReference users =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
      final String uid = firebaseUser.uid;
      String url = downloadUrl;
      await users.doc(uid).update({'url': url});

      //Trying to also update users' comments document with the image

      final CollectionReference posts =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts");
      await posts
          .doc()
          .collection('comments')
          .doc()
          .update({'profilePic': url});
```

How can I possibly achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the Firestore Database Screenshot from the Firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
await users.doc(uid).update({'url': url}).then((value2) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .doc('postDOCID')
          .collection('comments')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: curUserUID)
          .get()
          .then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
                element.data().update('userImageURL', (value) => "url");
              }));
    });
```

Basically, what you will need to do is loop through or search with where through post documents where userId = currentUpdatedUID.

Once you find it, loop the list and update each one of them.

Let me know if any issue comes up.

Cheers!!